# Replacing flexible hose from 1.5 bowl sink

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink, uk

I have a 1.5 bowl sink in my kitchen. The smaller bowl has a flexible ridged hose that connects to the main bowls drain.

As it's a flexible hose it suffers from regular clogging due to the ridged surfaces, the drain can also be difficult to unclog. After a vigorous unclogging last night the hose became disconnected from underneath the smaller bowl and deposited water in my kitchen cabinets.

I've reconnected the hose (simply by pushing it on) but I am looking to replace the flexible ridged hose either with a solid pipe or a flexible pipe with either minimal or no ridges.

Do hoses of this size and design exist and is the current hose setup easy to remove, or would I also need to remove the main drain pipework?

[image: Hose]

[image: connection]

[image: sink]

Comment: Your real problem appears to be a lack of head height at the wall drain.  Are you able to lower the elevation at the wall?  That would allow you to get some more slope on your side sink drain, which would help reduce clogging.  An alternative idea would be to rearrange your traps so that both sinks share a trap, or each has their own trap.

Comment: There are quite a few different types of hoses.  Not sure if it is the picture, but there does not seem to enough slope in the flex pipe.  You want about 1/4 inch slope on horizontal sections.

Comment: Perhaps a sieve on the drain in the sink bowl would reduce the clogging...

Comment: Hoses that are easy to push on, are also very easy to pull off when draining water.  Should at least have a hose clamp to hold it on a bit better, till it is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what a "1.5 bowl sink" is, but that thing is tiny, as is the drain!

I'm not sure where in the world you are that this might be a common plumbing arrangement, nor what plumbing products are available to you, but it appears to me that the only reason the flexible hose is needed is because the connector on the main bowl isn't installed conveniently.

I'm willing to bet that the grey fitting on the bottom of the main bowl can be turned clockwise (when looking into the sink from the top) so that the entry point for that flex hose moves from roughly the 1 o'clock position to the 3 o'clock position. That will point the entry directly at the drain from the small "1.5 bowl", and allow you to use standard, solid piping to run the drain from the smaller bowl.

I'm not sure what plumbing parts are available locally to you, so it's hard to make specific recommendations. I'd guess that the existing line is roughly 1" (25mm) copper piping (maybe only 3/4" (18mm)), and that might be a starting point for your to start looking. I'd also suggest taking that flexible pipe with you to the store so you can compare it to pipe & fittings at the store to figure out what you need. You may be able to find parts at a larger "Home Improvement" store, but you'd probably have greater success finding the needed bits at a dedicated plumbing supply store. Be sure to take your pictures and parts with you so they can help you identify what you need.